# What is the purpose of using hex escape sequences when writing buffer overflow exploits?

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit-development

I was trying to overwrite `fp` function pointer to `0x8048424`(`win()` location) so that function `win()` will be called to solve this problem(machine is little endian)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void win()
{
  printf("code flow successfully changed\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  volatile int (*fp)();
  char buffer[64];

  fp = 0;

  gets(buffer);

  if(fp) {
      printf("calling function pointer, jumping to 0x%08x\n", fp);
      fp();
  }
}
```

I am able to do this by overflowing `buffer`variable and then overwriting `fp`
by doing `python -c "print'A'*64 + '\x24\x84\x04\x08'" | ./stack3`.

But my question is *why* we need hex escape sequences?I have saw this notation in many tutorials but none of them explained it *purpose*

I read about this and found that they can be used as escape sequences. for e.g `\n`(which is a newline character) can be written as `printf("\x0A")` and it will do the same thing. So it makes sense.

But when overwriting memory why we need this? I didn't understand it's purpose here in buffer overflow
Why we cannot simply use `python -c "print'A'*64 + '0x24840408'" | ./stack3`. I mean we are just writing a memory address to a pointer variable.

PS  My question is related to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180145/trying-to-buffer-overflow-simple-c-program/180159#180159) but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question that Why do we need `\x` notation in first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hex escape sequence `\x{whatever}` represents a single byte of data. That byte can represent different things depending on the program reading it. For instance, `\x78` could represent the character `"x"`, the number 120, 'the 120th byte of the following section', or any special meaning assigned to it in context. If you write the string of characters `"0x24840408"`, it'll be interpreted as the string of bytes `\x30\x78\x32\x34\x38\x34\x30\x34\x30\x38` (you may notice that the characters `"0"` to `"9"` are represented by `\x30` to `\x39`). When you write character strings here, they're simply interpreted as the corresponding string of bytes, the computer doesn't look at what characters those bytes represent. When your debugger prints out the address `"0x8048424"`, it's not printing what's actually stored in memory - it's trying to be helpful by interpreting the four byte sequence `\x24\x84\x04\x08` that's actually there and printing a string of characters humans can understand (Also it can't print `\x24\x84\x04\x08` as the characters it represents because three of those characters are either unprintable or invisible).

It would be possible for a program to convert the other way and turn `"0x24840408"` (or indeed `"0x8048424"`) into `\x84\x24\x04\x08` in memory, but the python interpreter doesn't do that by default because it's not often needed outside of exploit development. If you really do mean 'put this four-byte value into memory verbatim', that's what escape sequences are for.

So, to summarise:
`"0x24840408"` is represented in memory by `\x30\x78\x32\x34\x38\x34\x30\x34\x30\x38
\x24\x84\x04\x08` represents `"$[three unprintable characters]"`* (ie. \x24 represents `$` - but we don't care what string it represents because we're interpreting it as an address)

*actually it'd usually be `"$[one unprintable character]"`. `\x08` as a character represents 'backspace', so it should remove the `\x04` before it. But that's not really the point.